# Golang yaml.v2 struct with a map[string]string unmarshalling fails

Tags: parsing, go, yaml

Im am using the gopkg.in/yaml.v2 package and I'm trying to unmarshal a yaml file like this:

```
Sizes: 
  A: small
  B: small
  C: medium
```

I created a go struct like this:

```
type sizesByType struct {
    Map map[string]string `yaml: "Sizes"`
}
```

but unmarshaling it with yaml.v2 gives me an empty map.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space in your struct tag:

```
type sizesByType struct {
    Map map[string]string `yaml:"Sizes"`
}
```